# Default samsung internet browser and Safari is not getting the lat long via $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, android, google-maps, safari

I have a working code to get city name and other names using `geocode` lat long via `$_POST` variable in geocode map url, it works fine on laptop and chrome in mobile but it is not working in Samsung default Internet Browser & iPhone Safari browser.

When I put lat long manually it works fine.

**This Doesnt work**

```
$latbt = $_POST['latitude'];
$lonbt = $_POST['longitude'];
$data = file_get_contents("https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".$latbt.','.$lonbt."&key=AIzaSyDqIj_SXTf5Z5DgE_cvxd5xdfttdNbuaiCbs&sensor=true");
```

**This Works Fine**

```
$latbt = 51.562957;
$lonbt = 17.089233;
$data = file_get_contents("https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".$latbt.','.$lonbt."&key=AIzaSyDqIj_SXTf5Z5DgE_cvxd5xdfttdNbuaiCbs&sensor=true");
```

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` what do you get back?

Comment: You should be using GET here, and not POST. Error reporting would have most likely thrown you an error about it, being undefined indexes.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  im getting this `array(0) {}`

Comment: Even `$_GET` is not working

Comment: anything from http://php.net/manual/pl/function.error-reporting.php ? you also tagged as javascript/android and if it's a related issue, I can't be of help for those. If you're using a form with a POST method but using `file.php?var` as an additional argument, then use `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: I am using form with POST method with submitting on body `onLoad`